# Monotonic transformation

Tags: real-analysis

I have an exercise:

Let $f : \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$ and $T : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a strictly monotonically increasing transformation. Show that $x*$ is a maximum of$f$ if and only if $x* $is a maximum of the transformed function $T o f.$

I would be very thankful if someone could show me how to solve this exercise as i am preparing for my calculus exam and don´t even know how to approach this exercise.

Comment: How about the Chain rule?

Answer (score 2):

(Fist $\Rightarrow$) The statement "$x^*\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is maximum of $~f$" is equivalent to 
$$ f(x^*)\geq f(x), ~\forall x \in\mathbb{R}^n.$$ Since $T$ is a strictly monotonically increasing transformation, then if $$ a\geq b \Rightarrow T(a)\geq T(b). $$ If you take $a = f(x^*)$ and $b=f(x)\in \mathbb{R}^n$, then you have
$$ T(f(x^*)) \geq T(f(x)),  \forall x\in \mathbb{R}^n $$ which proves the first part.

(Second $\Leftarrow$) The statement "$x^*\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a maximum of $~T\circ f$" is equivalent to 
$$ T\circ f(x^*)\geq  T\circ f(x), ~\forall x \in\mathbb{R}^n.$$
Since $T$ is a strictly monotonically increasing transformation, then it is invertible and if $$ T(a)\geq T(b) \Rightarrow a\geq b. $$
By choosing $a = f(x^*)$ and $b = f(x)$, we have that
$$ f(x^*) \geq f(x), \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n $$
which proves the second part.